# AsyncFileUpload postback causes double upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, asyncfileupload

I implemented the `AsyncFileUpload` control on a web page. This web page requires uploaded files to appear in a `GridView`.
The `GridView` contains the following columns: "*File Name*", "*Confidential*" Check Box, and a "*Remove*" button to remove the uploaded file.

Since the `AsyncFileUpload` postback does not do a *full page* postback, I need to "force" a postback on the `OnClientUploadComplete` event of the AsyncFileUpload control in order to render the gridview after uploading a file.
In the `OnClientUploadCompleteEvent`, I use javascript to call `__doPostBack`. In this postback, I only bind my GridView and display the file information (I don’t re-save the file).

The problem: **On the `AsyncFileUpload`’s first “partial” postback, the file is successfully uploaded, as expected. On the second postback that I force with `__doPostBack`, the file is re-uploaded.**
You can verify this by using Google Chrome, which displays the upload progress. The behaviour is as follows:
 - After selecting the file, the progress increments from 0% to 100% and the file is uploaded.
 - After this, the `__doPostBack` executes, and you can see the upload progress increment again from 0% to 100%.

How can I make sure the Gridview is properly populated, but that the file is not uploaded twice?

I attached a sample solution which contains the issue:  https://www.yousendit.com/download/MzZFc2ZBNDRrYUN4dnc9PQ

Comment: Please help me @user619814 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682909/display-gridview-after-upload-file-in-asyncfileupload-in-updatepanel-asp-net-c-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe ugly, but works:

---

1)
Add a css-hidden asp:Button bellow the asp:AsyncFileUpload `AsyncFileUpload1` control.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClick" Text="Update grid" style="display:none"/>
```

2)
On the `Page_Load` method, remove the `if (Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET") == "UploadPostback")` and put its block in a simple `else` to the previous `if`.

3)
On the `AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete` function, also remove the `if (Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET") != "UploadPostback")` line, but leave intact everything that was inside it.

4)
Back to the aspx. Put a asp:UpdatePanel outside the grid GridView1.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnClick" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
     <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ...
     YOUR GRID CODE REMAINS THE SAME
     </asp:GridView>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

5)
The last step is to change the `AjaxUploadComplete` client-side javascript function to make it trigger the postback.
Replace it with the following:

```
function AjaxUploadComplete() {
    var btnClick = document.getElementById("btnClick");
    btnClick.click();
}
```

---

Any file the user selects is uploaded only once.
All changes here are meant to be made in AjaxUpload.aspx & AjaxUpload.aspx.cs of your AjaxUpload.zip.

Comment: This wouldn't be quite what I would code to accomplish this kind of behavior, but I made the fewer possible changes so your goals would be met.

Comment: Thanks tiagoinu, your solution does the job.  You rock!

Comment: Please help me @tiagoinu : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682909/display-gridview-after-upload-file-in-asyncfileupload-in-updatepanel-asp-net-c-s

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler solution

> @@t0x1n3Himself the solution u gave is very simple but does not work

surround the AsyncFileUpload with an update panel name it **UpdatePanelAFU**
then in the UpdatePanelAFU do as the following :

```
 protected void AsyncFileUpload_UpdatePanelAFU(object sender,AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{

    if (Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET") != "UpdatePanelAFU")
        return;
..... rest of the code 
}
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Veera had it right. UploadComplete was being called multiple times as the file was uploading.  The following worked for me.

```html
void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e) {
    if (AsyncFileUpload1.IsUploading) return;
    // rest of your upload code
}
```

Comment: A little late here but I have the same issue and tried using IsUploading but I get "undefined" returned for AsyncFileUpload1.IsUploading (assuming the control ID was AsyncFileUpload1, wrapped in UpdatePanel)

Comment: Make sure you have the AsyncFileUpload control.  Chances are you didn't get a reference to the control and it's NULL (nothing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your sample solution which contains the issue but i encounter a double postback too in my project with the AsyncFileUpload component.
I found a very simple workaround :

Just add:

```
private bool justUploaded = false;
```

Then:

```
void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (justUploaded) return;
    justUploaded = true;
    // rest of your upload code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this a more elegant solution, found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1951566.aspx?AsyncFileUpload+uploads+twice) but below is my altered fully working code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>AsyncFileUpload Example</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function uploadComplete(sender) {
            $get("<%=lblMesg.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "File Uploaded Successfully";
            clearContents();
        }


        function uploadError(sender) {
            $get("<%=lblMesg.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "File upload failed.";
            clearContents();
        }


    function clearContents() {
            var span = $get("<%=AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID%>");
            var txts = span.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < txts.length; i++) {
                if (txts[i].type == "text") {
                    txts[i].value = "";
                }
                if (txts[i].type == "file") {
                    txts[i].value = "";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <cc1:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
            OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server"
            ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern" EnableViewState = "false"
            UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF"  ThrobberID="imgLoader" OnUploadedComplete = "FileUploadComplete"
          />
        <asp:Image ID="imgLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl = "~/images/loader.gif" />
        <br />
       <asp:Label ID="lblMesg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>






    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncFileUpload` has a property that named `IsUploading`.
when this property is set to false, a  `postback` will happen.
you can check this property like this:

```
if(AsyncFileUpload1.IsUploading)
 {
  ..... upload codes
 }
```