# AsyncFileUpload UploadedComplete is called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, asyncfileupload

I am using AsyncFileupload. File is uploaded perfectly but twice, as the event OnUploaded complete is fired twice. I am using two Update panels as shown below

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelTop" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonSave" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <uc1:Alert ID="Alert1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelAdminUpload" runat="server"
        Width="90%">..........some code here .....
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelAFU">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>File: </td>
                    <td class="style1">


                                                    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUploadPub" runat="server"
                            ToolTip="Select the file"
                            OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUploadPub_UploadedComplete"
                            OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"
                            UploaderStyle="Modern" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" ThrobberID="myThrobber" />
                        &nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" ID="myThrobber" Style="display: none;"><img align="middle" alt="" src="../Styles/images/Animated Gif/Uploading.gif" /></asp:Label>

                        <asp:Label ID="LabelOpt" runat="server" Text="(Optional) "></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>File Details:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFileDetails" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
     ......some code here ....    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is postback causes the file upload twice a time. The following link has the solution please have a look into that.

[AsyncFileUpload postback causes double upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018044/asyncfileupload-postback-causes-double-upload)

Might be this will be helpful

Comment: I found the solution myself and posted the answer in the thread u indicated